# CORS error for rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cors

I am building a rails API and when I send a request to it from an app (on a different subdomain than the API) I get the following response:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.myapp.dev/v1/posts/create. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

I don't understand why this is happening, since in my rails controller I have set `headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'`.

My `app/routes.rb file`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    # Take care of CORS
    match "*all", to: "api#cors_preflight_check", via: [:options]

    # Routes for posts
    get 'posts(/index)', :to => 'posts#index'
    post 'posts/create'
    delete 'posts/:id', :to => 'posts#destroy'
    get 'posts/show'
    put 'posts/:id', :to => 'posts#update'

    # Routes for post comments
    get 'posts/:post_id/comments(/index)', :to => 'comments#index'
    post 'posts/:post_id/comments/create', :to => 'comments#create'
    delete 'posts/:post_id/comments/:id', :to => 'comments#destroy'
    put 'posts/:post_id/comments/:id', :to => 'comments#update'

  end
end
```

My `app/controllers/v1/api_controller.rb file`:

```
module V1  
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
    before_filter :cors_preflight_check
    after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

    def cors_set_access_control_headers
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
    end

    def cors_preflight_check
      if request.method == "OPTIONS"
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
        headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
        render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly easiest thing to do is use [this](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) and then set up your configuration in the config/application.rb file.